# Passing a directory path to create a dictionary instead of a list.

Tags: python, regex, parsing, email, word-count

Essentially I want to sort of do a makeshift super word count, but I'm uncertain how to create a dict object from a directory path (passed in as an argument) as opposed to a list to do what I need to do.

While I want to create a dictionary object, I also want to format the ASCII values of the keys which are filenames into email or message objects using the email module. Then I want to extract the body using the payload and parse it that way. I have some example below:

```
mylist=os.listdir(sys.stdin)
for emails in mylist:
    email_str = emails.open()
    #uncertain if this will get all emails and their content or not
    #all emails are supposed to have a unique identifier, they are essentially still just ascii
    file_dict = {emails : email_str}
#file_dict = dict(zip(mylist, mylist))
for emails in file_dict[emails]:
    msg = email.message_from_string(email_str)
    body = msg.get_payload(decode=True)
    #I'm not entirely sure how message objects and sub objects work, but I want the header to 
    #signature and I'm not sure about the type of emails as far as header style
    #pretend I have a parsing method here that implements the word count and prints it as a dict:
    body.parse(regex)
```

I don't entirely need the keys other than to parse their values so I may consider using message_from_file instead.

Comment: Is this pseudocode? Its extremely far from anything functional, so I am not sure where to start commenting for an answer.

Comment: yeah pretty much pseudo. my comments pretty much imply that.

Comment: Yes but I think you may have oversimplified your example to the point where I can't tell what part you are  having trouble with. You are saying you can get all the email bodies into a proper list, but you can't figure out how to get them into a dictionary where the key is the original file name?

Comment: well I think I made a mistake and forgot to mention that the file name is essentially the name of the email itself. So the key is the email file's name and the email itself is the value, but I need to extract the body from the value. Afterwards use wc on that body.

Comment: No I totally figure that part out already. What I am saying is its not specifically clear what part you need the help with. Do you need to know how to create a dictionary? How to read the body of emails? How to read files from disk? You need to update this question to specifically show what you are having trouble with and not have this vague pseudocode.

Comment: Yes for help on creating a dictionary but only in this context. I know how to create a dictionary normally. To read the body of emails, yes in the sense that I am not sure what about email formats. In terms of reading files from disk, yes in the sense that I need to read files to set as values for keys being file names.

Comment: Just gave you the best answer I am capable of giving with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any string as a file path, and you can even use relative file paths.  If you're just trying to format data for yourself, you could do iterate through your list of email messages and store the output.

```
for emailpath in list_of_email_paths
    emailpath = 'someemailpath'
    # open path -- only works if path exists.
    f = open(emailpath)
    file_dict[emailpath] = f.read()
    f.close()
```

Not a great idea to use open file objects as keys (if it's even possible, just read them and store a string as an identifier. Read the docs on [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) for more (btw - you have to import with `import os`, not `import os.path`)

Aside from that, any immutable object or reference can be a dictionary key, so there's no problem with storing paths as keys. Python doesn't care where the path came from, nor does the dict care if its keys are paths ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because you are asking to be shown so much information at once, my answer has to be a bit more general to overview them. Even though you stated that your example is all purely pseudocode, its all so completely wrong that its hard to know what you understand and what parts you don't, so I will cover all the bases of what you said in your comments.

**How to read files**

You are misusing [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.listdir), as it takes a string path, not a file-type object. But personally for this I like to use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob). It saves a few steps in letting you get the full path, and filtered by a pattern. Lets assume all your email files end in `.mail`

```
import sys
import glob

first_path = sys.argv[1]
pattern = "%s/*.mail" % first_path
for mail in glob.iglob(pattern):
    # with context will close the file automatically
    with open(main) as f:
        data = f.read()
        # do something with data here
```

**Parsing email formats**

The example for using the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module are extensive, so there is no point in me showing them here other than giving you a link to review: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html
If the files are actually emails, then you should be able to use this module to parse them and read the message body of each one

**Using a dictionary**

Using a dictionary is no different in this case than in any general case of a python dict. You would start by creating an empty dict:

```
file_dict = {}
```

And on every loop of your directory listing you will always have the string path name, which you wanted to be your key. Whether you read the files raw data using the first example, or you used the email module to get the message body, either way you will end up with some chunk of text data.

```
for mail in glob.iglob(pattern):
    ...
    # do stuff to get the text data from the file
    data = some_approach_to_reading_file()
    ...
    file_dict[mail] = data
```

Now you have a `file_dict` with the key being the path to the original file, and the value being the read data.

**Summary**

With these three sections, you should have plenty of general information to put this all together.

Comment: thanks. On that sys.stdin I was actually planning on passing in a path though as a string, not a file type object which I think you can do via the terminal.

Comment: @Nightvein: You can either READ sys.stdin to get strings which would be if you were piping to your command, or you can get them from sys.argv. This is what I was talking about regarding you example. While you may call it pseudocode, it looks like you don't know how to code in python, and suggests you might be asking for a complete lesson. Hopefully what I wrote worked for you though?